# Why does EntityFramework populate my NotMapped field with a trash value

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

Hello i am retrieving a `IEnumerable<Something>` using Entity Framework and this `Something` has an `IEnumerable<SomethingElse>` property that has the attribute `[NotMapped]` over it.

Why does entity framework populate this `IEnumerable<SomethingElse>` field  with some unknown object that is neither `null` but can't be interogated with `Linq` throwing the following exception:

`System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')'`

```
public class Something
{  
   [NotMapped]
   public IEnumerable<SomethingElse> Items{get;set;}
}

public struct SomethingElse
{
    //some fields
}
```

**Insertion**:
When i insert the list some elements have the `NotMapped` field null, while others not:

```
List<Something> toBeInserted=new List<Something>{ new Something{Items=null},new Something{Items=new[]{ new SomethingElse{}}};

//dbcontext insert the list....
```

**Retrieval**

```
List<Something>somethings=(await this.[SomeDBContext].Somethings).ToList();
```

Now at retrieval some elements have the `NotMapped` property null as it should be,while someothers have this weird non-null `IEnumerable<SomethingElse>d_6`that throws exception on any `Linq` interogation:

```
var weirdElement=somethings.First();
weirdElement.Items.Count(); //throws
weirdElement.Items.Any();throws
```

**P.S**
 I have checked this [post](https://daveaglick.com/posts/computed-properties-and-entity-framework) regarding computed properties and it says:
 `Materialize the list when you fetch it from the database to resolve the computed properties`.
That is what i have done.
I issue `(await this.DBContext.Somethings).ToList()` to no avail.
Some `Something`'s still have their `IEnumerable<SomethingElse>` property not null.

**Later Edit**

This is a picture with what the 
not mapped property of the element looks like:
[image]

I am computing the `IEnumerable<SomethingElse>` using an `extension method`:

```
public class Extension
{
    public static IEnumerable<SomethingElse> Compute(this IEnumerable<SomethingSomethingElse> someOthers){}
}
```

The name of the type of the field `IEnumerable<SomethingElse>` is `<Compute>d_6`

Comment: What version of EF?  Do you have Lazy Loading enabled?

Comment: What do you mean by lazy loading enabled.Isn't it enabled whenever i am using an `IEnumerable` or derived classes?I am `EF Core 3.1.2`

Comment: Latest version of EF6 or EF Core?  They are both current branches.  And Lazy Loading will replace your Something with a runtime subtype proxy.  So examine the runtime type with `wierdElement.GetType().Name`.

Comment: I am using `EF Core 3.1.2` with `EF Core 3.1.0 Design` + `EF Core Relational 3.1.0` +`EF Core SqlServer 3.1.0 `. Just `EF Core ` is `3.1.2` the rest are `3.1.0`.

Comment: The name of the type of the field is `<[ExtensionMethodName]>d__6`. The `ExtensionMethodName` is the name of the extension method that computes this field.

Comment: Is it a streaming IEnumerable implementation, or does it return a List<SomethingElse>?  If it it's streaming, then the method body doesn't actually run until you enumerate the collection.

Comment: If by streaming implementation  you mean if i am using `yield` in the `Compute` method then yes it is streaming.Why does `EF` not populate the `Notmapped` field with `null` and instead calls the extension method ?

Comment: It doesn't.  this has nothing to do with EF.  Except perhaps the non-obvious behavior that if you query the DbContext and it already has the entity in the Change Tracker it will return the tracked entity instance instead of one constructed from the database results.